# PHP compare current time with times in array and return related value

Tags: php, time, compare

I need to compare current time with times in array and accordingly return related value.
So I have array like this:

```
$class[0]["start"] = 80000;
$class[0]["end"] = 80500;
$class[0]["title"] = "Warmup";

$class[1]["start"] = 80501;
$class[1]["end"] = 85000;
$class[1]["title"] = "1. class";

$class[2]["start"] = 85001;
$class[2]["end"] = 90000;
$class[2]["title"] = "Break";
```

And I need compare it with current time:

```
$time = (int) date('Gis');
```

I could do it the hardcoded way like this :

```
    if($time >= $class[1]["start"] && $time <= $class[1]["end"]) {
        $title = $class[1]["title"];
    } elseif($time >= $class[2]["start"] && $time <= $class[2]["end"]) {
        $title = $class[2]["title"];
etc ...
```

but I believe there is a better way how to return the "title" of the class without writing hundreds lines of elseif.

Any idea?

Thanx

Maros

Comment: Seems like you're looking for the first value where `end` is greater than current?

Comment: yes, that is also point of view ... hmmm ... for now I cannot find any way to search for it in multi array, but I need some time to google it ...

Comment: and of course, I can change the array according to my wishes, so maybe that will get me closer ...

Comment: A simple `foreach` over the `$class` array can do this.

Comment: yes, but still not too elegant ..... I'm thinking about something like array_filter($classes, function($n){ 
  return $n <= $time;
 }); but so far I'm not sure ...

Comment: Why would that be more elegant than a straightforward loop? Just because it takes up less lines? Strive for clear and efficient code, not one-line wonders. You can break out of a loop as soon as a result is found, as opposed to using array functions which will go through the entire array. I'd write a custom function that does this and return from it.

Comment: you are right in efficiency - I believed that one function that brings result is more efficient than iterating over maybe hundred arrays till getting to the breaking loop with correct answer ... but maybe not ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just do this..

```
<?php 
$time = (int) date('Gis');

$class[0]["start"] = 80000;
$class[0]["end"] = 80500;
$class[0]["title"] = "Warmup";

$class[1]["start"] = 80501;
$class[1]["end"] = 85000;
$class[1]["title"] = "1. class";

$class[2]["start"] = 85001;
$class[2]["end"] = 90000;
$class[2]["title"] = "Break";

foreach($class as $val){ 

      if($time >= $val["start"] && $time <= $val["end"]) {
        $title .= $val["title"];
         } 
  }

echo $title;


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on El_Vanja's comment, you could just split looping your array and filtering its data in two separate functions, so your code becomes both more sparse and more readable.

For example, given your array:

```php
$class = [

    [
        "start" => 80000,
        "end"   => 80500,
        "title" => "Warmup",
    ],

    [
        "start" => 80501,
        "end"   => 85000,
        "title" => "1. class",
    ],

    [
        "start" => 85001,
        "end"   => 90000,
        "title" => "Break",
    ],
];
```

You could do something like this:

```php
function is_between(int $value, int $low, int $high) {

    return ($value >= $low && $value <= $high);
}

function filter(array $data, int $time) {

    foreach ($data as $row) { 

        if (is_between($time, $row['start'], $row['end'])) {

            return $row;
        }
    }
}
```

And simply call it like this:

```php
var_dump(filter($class, 80100));
var_dump(filter($class, 86000));
var_dump(filter($class, 80600));
```

Comment: Happy to hear. BTW: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers